Calculated field to detail marks of 30+ worksheets
Is there a way to add calculated field to Detail marks of multiple worksheets in Tableau in bulk, or do I have to do this one at a time?
Selecting multiple worksheet and adding it to Detail marks did not work. I only have one data source tied to all these Worksheets.

One at a time in desktop, but you may be able to do it in bulk through the REST API.
If your worksheets are more or less the same format/ structure, build your one sheet, and on its tab at the bottom, right click and duplicate sheet and change your pills/ variables/ columns as needed.
